# Check if Input is Binary

Tags: python, binary

I have this code. I just can't figure out how to make it that only "1" and "0" are accepted.

```
a = input('Enter a binary number : ')
ar = [int(i) for  i in a]
ar  = ar[::-1]
res = []
for i in range(len(ar)):
    res.append(ar[i]*(2**i))
sum_res = sum(res)      
print('Decimal Number is : ',sum_res)
```

Comment: Just to note: you can just do `print('Decimal Number is:', int(a, 2))`... which'll do what you want and raise an exception if it isn't a valid binary number

Comment: In this case: How to print e.g. "Your number is invalid"? With "else"?

Comment: You don't use an `else`... you use a `try/except` block

Answer (score 0):

You can use `isdigit()` or `isnumeric()`method to allow integers only and use `any()` to check whether number is binary or not. So, it needs to be like this

```
if a.isnumeric():
    if any([int(i) > 1 for i in a]):
        print("Please enter binary numbers only!")
    else:
        #some code
else:
     print("Please enter integers only!")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the int constructor with base argument:

```
    try:
        user_bin = int(input('Binary number: '), 2)
    except ValueError:
        print('Binary digits 0-1 only allowed.')
    else:
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few approaches you can follow:

- as described in other posts, you could catch the exception of `int`. Having said that, given that you are rewriting a method which essentially mimics what `int(...,2)` does, maybe it is a little bit *illogical*!
- you could see if all the elements of the string you entered are `0` or `1`, adding in your code a check like this after the input:

  ```
  if not all(map(lambda x: x in ["0", "1"], list(a))):
      print("Only values '0' or '1' should be entered")
      return
  ```
- you could use *good old* regular expressions:

  ```
  import re
  pattern = re.compile("^[0-1]+$")

  ...

  if not pattern.match(a):
      print("Only values '0' or '1' should be entered")
      return
  ```